# Automate file uploading from Sharepoint to Azure Storage Container

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

**What I am trying to implement** -

When a user uploads a CSV file to the sharepoint in a particular directory, a new blob is created on the Azure Storage Container for the same file creating all it's contents.

**Problem** -

I haven't been able to copy the contents of the CSV which is uploaded on Sharepoint. I am able to set the trigger point which is working fine. But the blocker has been the accessing of the file contents. How do I do this?

Below is the current logic app design that I have implemented, I am unsure of what to add in the File Identifier or is there a better way I can implement the same design?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File Identifier should be one of the values available in the dynamic data from "When a file is created (properties only)". Looks like it is "Identifier".
[image]

This is a very common use case, almost hello-world level between Azure and M365 using Logic Apps, there is a plethora of blogs and YouTube on this. Here is one example I found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nr2QJBbsBRU

Don't hesitate to respond with any questions!